# Writing check that all pandas DataFrame column values meet a certain values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exception, conditional-statements

I'm writing checks for a software package. The elements within a pandas DataFrame meet certain conditions; if they don't, I will raise a `ValueError` exception written within Python.

Here is an example pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict1 = {'file': ['filename2', 'filename2', 'filename3', 'filename4', 
         'filename4', 'filename3'], 'amount': [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1], 
         'front': [21889611, 36357723, 196312, 11, 42, 1992], 
         'back':[21973805, 36403870, 277500, 19, 120, 3210], 
         'type':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df1)

        file  amount     front      back type
0  filename2       3  21889611  21973805    A
1  filename2       4  36357723  36403870    A
2  filename3       5    196312    277500    A
3  filename4       1        11        19    B
4  filename4       2        42       120    B
5  filename3       1      1992      3210    C
```

The most efficient way I've seen to check that certain values is to use `sets`, e.g. if column `type` contains elements that are not `A`, `B`, or `C`, throw an error:

```
if not set(['A', 'B', 'C']).issubset(df1['type']):
    raise ValueError('Pandas DataFrame contains improper values in "type" column')
```

Question:

How would I most efficiently check conditionals? e.g. I would like to check that column `amount` contains integers greater than 0. If there are any zeros, negative integers, or non-integers in this column, raise a `ValueError()`.

Comment: `df1.amount.gt(100).all()`

Comment: @Wen This is a pretty good solution. In the above example, it would be ` 
df1.amount.gt(0).all()`

Comment: You can test it : -)

Comment: I would also use `isinstance()` above to check it's an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just filter on a column, get the length of the dataframe returned and use that in your if statement:

```
len(df1[df1['amount'] > 0])
```

Comment: This is a good idea. I'll have to time this against `df1.amount.gt(0).all()`

Comment: Keep in mind you could just target the series too `len(df1['amount'] > 0)`. I just used the result dataframe because it also allows access to the whole row should you need to provide that info when a ValueError is thrown.